# What is the C++ equivalent using std::priority_queue (C++ STL) of this Java code

Tags: java, c++, priority-queue

basically, it's gonna be a min-heap of vectors where priority is based on index 1 (0-based) of the vector.

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> (a[1] - b[1]));
```

I tried

```
priority_queue<<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, [](vector<int> a[1], vector<int> b[1]){
return a[1] < b[1];
}>
```

Comment: I am bad when it comes to comparators and lambda functions

Comment: `vector<int> a[1]`?? Are you confused about valid parameter names or are you really trying to accept a 1-element array of vectors here?

Comment: there is no real equivalent of this in c++. You wouldn't use `new` to create an instance, `pq` would be an object, not just a reference, C++ has no generics, it has templates but thats something very different.

Comment: for vectors if you want to sort based on index 1 you usually do      sort(intervals.begin(), intervals.end(), [](vector<int> a, vector<int> b){
            return a[1] < b[1];
        }); I Just tried to mimic that here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of the queue are vectors, and thus that is the type of object that are being compared to each other. `vector<int> a[1]` is not a vector, but an array of vectors of length 1 (although as a function argument, it will be adjusted in this case to be a pointer to the element of that array i.e. pointer to vector). As such, the argument type of the comparison object doesn't match the element type of the container and is thus wrong.

One way to fix it is to change the argument to be a reference to const qualified element of the queue - you will want to use a reference in order to avoid unnecessarily copying the vectors on each comparison. But perhaps even simpler is to use `auto` so that the type is deduced like it is in the Java example:

```
auto cmp = [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
    return a[1] < b[1];
}
```

Furthermore, the comparison object is not a template argument. The template argument is the type of the comparison object. Lastly, your example lacks a name for the variable. A fixed example:

```
priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
```

For maximal type deduction, you could use the constructor that accepts the underlying container as argument:

```
vector<vector<int>> v; // you may optionally populate the queue here
priority_queue pq {cmp, std::move(v)};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to  use a lambda as a comparator the usual way to do it is  this

```cpp
auto cmp = [](vector<int> a, vector<int> b) { return a[0] < b[0]; };

priority_queue<vector<int>, vector<vector<int>>, decltype(cmp)> Q(cmp);
```

And usually the arguments to the comparator would be of type `const vector<int>&`, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
struct comparator { 
    bool operator()(pair<int,int> const& a, pair<int,int> const& b) 
    { 
        return a.second > b.second;
    } 
}; 
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,comparator>Q;
```